Clone existing disc in azure
is it possible to clone the OS-Disk from VM A to be used in VM b (different resource group) best case deployed by terraform?
i tried using (with an snapshot of os disk from VM a):
os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "StandardSSD_LRS"
    managed_disk_id = "foo/baa"
  }

Thank you

This might fit better on [sf] (check the guidelines first). Off-topic here, though, as it's not related to programming.

It's done in a storage_os_disk block. Assuming you already created a managed disk from the snapshot:
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "osdisk"
    create_option     = "Attach"
    managed_disk_id   = "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group_name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/<disk_name>"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
  }

